# invalid JSON format, cant view it as a tree

Tags: json

I tried to view my JSON file as a tree and I got an error that I don't know how to solve.

error:
`Parse error on line 1: ...2","Likes":"0/0"}} {"Id":2,"commContent ----------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'`

JSON output:`{"Id":1,"commContent":{"Name":"username1","Comment":"text1","Date":"5.5.2021 10:22","Likes":"0/0"}} {"Id":2,"commContent":{"Name":"username2","Comment":"text2","Date":"5.5.2021 10:24","Likes":"0/0"}}`

Json online editor Iam using: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON to me.  The JSON has two entities in it that are not in an array.  The error message is telling you this - it's expecting EOF and instead a new element started.

Comment: Your output contains two json elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the JSON you have produced.  You have two distinct elements in the JSON but they are not in an array, so the tree looks like this:

- Root element
- Root element

The error messages is correctly identifying the problem - it is expecting `EOF` but instead is receiving a new element starting with `{`.

That doesn't make any sense - the elements probably need to be nested in an array (surrounded with `[]` and with a comma `,` between), like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "commContent": {
      "Name": "username1",
      "Comment": "text1",
      "Date": "5.5.2021 10:22",
      "Likes": "0/0"
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "commContent": {
      "Name": "username2",
      "Comment": "text2",
      "Date": "5.5.2021 10:24",
      "Likes": "0/0"
    }
  }
]
```

The above would be considered valid.

Comment: Ah, I understand, thank you! Now I just have to figure out how to edit my C# code to make it work.

Comment: @Bur3vo In C# the above JSON would be considered an array\list of objects, if that helps.  Please remember to upvote or accept the answer if it is the right one.

Comment: I cant upvote, but I acceptd the answer. Everything works now, code is edited. Thank you :-)

Comment: Well, code soultion is kinda stupid but it works. When i create json file I write "[" in first line.. then in foreach same input as before, ending with ","  and when foreach ends I just delete last line containing "," and write "]" instead haha